Blender 4.1 on CPU render farm
In the studio where I work, we want to upgrade from Blender 3.5 to Blender 4.1.
Installing the software itself isn't an issue, but I need to open the program to install addons like GeoScatter.
The problem is that our render farm operates solely on CPUs.
In the previous version, we could use an OpenGL32.dll file to simulate a graphics card, but now it requires OpenGL 4.3, and I can't find a corresponding DLL file online.
Does such a DLL exist?
Or is there another way to install the addons without opening Blender?
Thanks in advance.

You don't have to install addons via the UI. You can put the addon's folder or .py file in one of the locations Blender is looking for addons in, such as in the Blender's application folder C:\blender\blender-3.6.10-windows-x64\3.6\scripts\addons or the user specific folder C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.6\scripts\addons.
You can enable addons via Python API in multiple ways. Like addon_utils.enable or with the --addons command line argument.
The Mesa OpenGL emulation works for OpenGL 4.3:  download https://github.com/pal1000/mesa-dist-win/releases/download/24.0.3/mesa3d-24.0.3-release-msvc.7z and put files opengl32.dll, libglapi.dll, libgallium_wgl.dll to the Blender's root folder next to blender.exe. Then add GALLIUM_DRIVER with value llvmpipe to your system environment variables. Tested for Blender 4.2.

Thanks for the answer, it really help us to find the solution.
here is how we done it :
We copy paste the addon into the blender folder at script/addon/ then launch in console command.
into a cmd window we navigate to the instal location of blender using the CD command.
C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 4.1
then we open blender with
blender -b --python-console
and finish the addon activation with those lines entered separetly
import bpy
bpy.ops.preferences.addon_enable(module='addonfoldername')
bpy.ops.wm.save_userpref()
and then Ctrl C to close the cmd blender properly
